# Action Chaining Not Redirecting After Controller.await(int millis)

Tags: playframework, continuation, async-await

I'm not sure if this isn't working as intended of it it's just me getting confused.

What I would like to do is to asynchronously delay an action, and `await(int millis)` and I seem to be able to become friends.

Here's what happens:

**1.** `Application.index` displays a form that sends a POST to `Application.something`.

**app/controllers/Application.java**

```
public static void index() {
    render();
}
```

**app/views/Application/index.html**

```
#{form @Application.something()}
    <input type="submit">
#{/form}
```

---

**2.** `Application.something` does its thing and then chains back to `index`.

**app/controllers/Application.java**

```
public static void something() {
    await(500);

    // Here be business

    index();
}
```

---

**3.** Play raises an application error: *"The template Application/something.html does not exist"*.

So when `render()` is called in `Application.index` after execution in `Application.something` has been suspended/resumed it tries to render the template of `Application.something`, which of course doesn't exist.

If I remove `await(500)` everything works just fine (the 302 is issued and `index` is rendered as expected).

I can force a redirect with

```
redirect("/");
```

and get the result I want, but this feels ugly.

I can also set

```
request.action = "Application.index";
```

manually right after the `await` and the render in `Application.index` works (actually, the magic in `Controller.template()` works) as intended.

---

So basically, is everything OK and I'm forced to live with using strings after `await` rather than method calls, or is something a bit off?

Cheers,
Tobias.

Answer (score 0):

When you call await() method, Play suspends this HTTP request. After the timeout, it starts again as a new HTTPRequest as if being called again.

In the first case, without the await() method, re-direction happens correctly - this is because this method call is correctly intercepted by the Play framework and Router reverse route generation creates the URL needed to issue a 302 re-direct. (Details in ActionChaining documentation)

But, in the second case, after the await() method, a new HTTPRequest is created and there is no action chaining happening - meaning the framework is not intercepting the call to index() method. This is executed like any other method, so you don't see the re-direct.

Comment: Thanks for answering, although it sounds like your explanation is for await pre-1.2 which didn't use continuations. I thought the point of await after 1.2 was to not rerun the entire request. :o